# unable to execute PHP files on my server

Tags: php, cpanel

While accessing PHP files in my server it prevents to execute PHP files. Image and text files etc can be browsed. When I try to browse PHP file it gives the following error:

> **The server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request.** The script had an error or it did not
>   produce any output. If there was an error, you should be able to see
>   it in the error log.

The .htaccess file is empty, I can access the cpanel but have no idea whats wrong.

Comment: Absolutely, yes I tried.

Comment: I found this line in the error log, but dont know what does that mean: suexec policy violation: see suexec log for more details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change your php files permission to 775.